# Linking with page id versus "pretty" permalinks in wordpress

Tags: seo, wordpress, permalinks

Assuming I am linking from one site I admin to another, so I have full control, is there a SEO difference in linking to the "pretty" permalink of a page versus using `/?page_id=x` or the "shortlink" generated by WP in the source of the page `/?p=x`?

I want to use one of the the latter options so I can avoid 404s when my customers change the slug of a page or article against my advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> is there a SEO difference in linking to the "pretty" permalink of a page versus using /?page_id=x or the "shortlink" generated by WP in the source of the page /?p=x?

There should be no difference at all. Google will assign benefit or penalty based on the anchor text, not the underlying link text and will re-assign benefit or penalty on the destination pages. `?page_id=x` or `?p=x` won't figure into it.

Comment: Well a link to `?p=x` will go through a 301 redirect to the pretty, final permalink. Does that not figure into it?

Comment: Not enough to matter. Almost everything WordPress does results in a 301 :)

Google knows a WordPress site when it spiders one and adjusts for stuff like this.

At the end of the day, you're not doing anything unusual enough to draw a penalty nor are you doing anything beneficial enough to draw a bonus.  Is there a micro-difference in the weightings? Yes. Does it matter in the grand scheme of things? No.

Comment: So you would say that the said 301 redirect is preferable to the speed disadvantage of using using the REST API to get the "pretty" permalink from the site I am linking to, correct?

Comment: Right now, yes. Google appears to highly value speed over number of redirects.  But since the algorithm changes frequently what is good today may be bad tomorrow. Generally speaking, I try to not overthink these things for that very reason.

Answer (score -1):

Firstly, WordPress manages 301 re-direct fine.

So, if you link to the URL with parameter vs clean URL would have the same value.

Let's understand by an example:

URL 1: example.com/detail-page-url/

URL 2: example.com/?page_id=1

Let's say URL 2 redirect so URL 1 then you can link either.

Even though it will have same value i would recommend linking the final preferred URL with is URL 1 because it looks clean and also got the keyword into it.

Not sure what you meant by 404 in your last line.

Hope this will help.

Comment: I think you misunderstood the original question.

Comment: Well, it answers the first part about 301. Not sure how you read the comment not related.